# UIScrollView autoresize contentSize?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

Fair warning, I'm fairly new to iOS and may be missing something obvious.

I have a `UIScrollView` with a few fields and those fields height can change (`UITextView` that stretches to fit text, collapsable fields etc). Obviously I want the scrollview `contenSize` to fit the content in order to allow scrolling.

Right now I have it set to re-calculate and set the `contentSize` every time something changes, which works fine but is there a better way to do it? In other words, if another developer now adds a field and doesn't remember to add it to the re-calculation function, unless I'm mistaken, the scrollview `contentSize` will be wrong even though the field is on the scrollview? Is there no way to have it "automatically" resize with it's content change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If autolayout is an option for you then go with it - as Tyler stated autolayout abstracts the resizing away for you! :)
Unfortunately i have no experience yet with autolayout, so I can't tell you more about that.

Without autolayout there is no better way as far as i know.
There's nothing like "sizeToFit" or "sizeThatFits" that would take over the task of resizing the content size automatically. You have to re-calculate the content size yourself. 
For that purpose either use your custom method for this re-calculation task or check out some 3rd-party categories on UIScrollView that allready have this implemented and abstracted away for you.

For example: [UIScrollView+MTUIAdditions.m](https://github.com/steipete/PSFoundation/blob/master/Categories/UIScrollView/UIScrollView+MTUIAdditions.m)
(see the implementation for `UIScrollView (MTUIAdditions)`)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a better way to accomplish this with autolayout. Apple has a very good document for using autolayout with scrollviews [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html). I prefer the pure autolayout approach, however in order to apply that approach you must ensure that the size of your fields are not dependent on the size of the scrollview, which makes sense. However make sure that your constraints extend to all the sides of the scroll view, so that the scrollview can determine the size of it's content.

(ie `@"H:|[textView(==view)]|"` and `@"V:|[textView(50)]|"` where '|' denotes the scrollView of which the textView is a subview and '==view' just specifies that the width of the textView must be the same as that of the view 'view'.)

Comment: Sadly I still need to support iOS5... But thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution

```
//autoresize scrollView
CGFloat scrollViewHeight = 0.0f;
CGFloat scrollViewWidth = 0.0f;
for (UIView *view in self.scrollView.subviews) {
    CGFloat height = (view.frame.size.height + view.frame.origin.y);
    scrollViewHeight = ((height > scrollViewHeight) ? height : scrollViewHeight);

    CGFloat width = (view.frame.size.width + view.frame.origin.x);
    scrollViewWidth = ((width > scrollViewWidth) ? width : scrollViewWidth);
}

[self.scrollView setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(scrollViewWidth, scrollViewHeight))];
```